# GitLab reports an error : PG::DuplicateSchema: ERROR: schema "gitlab_partitions_dynamic" already exists

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

Installed by GitLab Docker Compose and upgraded according to the official documentation

```
docker compose pull
docker compose up -d
```

The gitlab container cannot be started, the detailed error log is as follows:

```
...
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::DuplicateSchema: ERROR:  schema "gitlab_partitions_dynamic" already exists
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/migrate/20181228175414_init_schema.rb:7:in `up'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:126:in `block in write_using_load_balancer'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/load_balancer.rb:112:in `block in read_write'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/load_balancer.rb:172:in `retry_with_backoff'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/load_balancer.rb:110:in `read_write'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:125:in `write_using_load_balancer'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:77:in `transaction'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database.rb:265:in `block in transaction'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database.rb:264:in `transaction'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/migrations/lock_retry_mixin.rb:31:in `ddl_transaction'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/db.rake:63:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'

Caused by:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DuplicateSchema: ERROR:  schema "gitlab_partitions_dynamic" already exists
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/migrate/20181228175414_init_schema.rb:7:in `up'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:126:in `block in write_using_load_balancer'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/load_balancer.rb:112:in `block in read_write'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/load_balancer.rb:172:in `retry_with_backoff'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/load_balancer.rb:110:in `read_write'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:125:in `write_using_load_balancer'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:77:in `transaction'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database.rb:265:in `block in transaction'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database.rb:264:in `transaction'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/migrations/lock_retry_mixin.rb:31:in `ddl_transaction'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/db.rake:63:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'

Caused by:
PG::DuplicateSchema: ERROR:  schema "gitlab_partitions_dynamic" already exists
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/migrate/20181228175414_init_schema.rb:7:in `up'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:126:in `block in write_using_load_balancer'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/load_balancer.rb:112:in `block in read_write'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/load_balancer.rb:172:in `retry_with_backoff'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/load_balancer.rb:110:in `read_write'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:125:in `write_using_load_balancer'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:77:in `transaction'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database.rb:265:in `block in transaction'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database.rb:264:in `transaction'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/database/migrations/lock_retry_mixin.rb:31:in `ddl_transaction'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/db.rake:63:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
STDERR: 
---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20221119-30-1pungg2" ----
Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20221119-30-1pungg2" returned 1
```

I tried to stop the gitlab container and restart it, still not working, how can I fix this, thanks!